Sed command with special characters
Can you please help me with this command?
What is its meaning?
sed 's/\"[0\\.Na]\\+ EUR\"//g' file.txt | sed '/^\"[^\"]*\",\\+\$/d'

Thank you!
I tried \"[0\\.Na]\\+ EUR\" on regex101, but i can't get it.
I think
\" matches the character "
[0\\.Na] matches a single character present in the list below [0\\.Na] (0 .Na)
\\+ matches the character +
ecc.
but doesn't work

\+ matches 1 or more of the preceding item, not the literal character +.

And " has no special meaning in regular expressions, there's no need to escape it.

\\+ matches at least one backslash. \\  matches a literal backslash, and + is a quantifier meaning 1 or more.

. is not a special character when it appears within [] so you don't have to escape it.

Perhaps simplifying the regexp will help, the above regexp is the same as sed 's/"[0\.Na]\+ EUR"//g' file.txt|sed '/^"[^"]*",\+$d'

@Barmar the OP is using BREs so the +s are just literal.

@potong no, \+ instead of \\+ would remove the match on \ and turn + into a repetition metachar in some seds (e.g. GNU sed).

@EdMorton does not ,\+ mean one or more ,'s when used without the -E option? I took it that was what the OP intended when adding in so many \ 's otherwise the + is not a metacharacter and stands for itself?

@potong what ,\+ means depends on the sed version but that's my point - the OP isn't using -E and does have ,\\+ rather than ,\+ so it just means comma backslash plus in every sed version and if you change it to ,\+ then that's not simplifying it, it's changing it to mean something different.

your regex reading is correct as far as I can tell.
sed 's/<regex>//g' file.txt will find every instance of that regex and replace it with nothing.
sed '/<regex>/d' will delete every line that has a match for that regex.
So it reads a file, strips the first regex out, and then deletes the lines that match the second regex. It's worth noting this won't affect the file; it will only print the output.

The 2nd sed's regex is NOT the same as the first's. It does delete lines, but only where " is the first char and ",+ ends the line (and any other chars in between cannot be ").

@shelter it's actually where ",\+$ ends the line. Count the \s :-).

Here's the breakdown of your 2 sed commands:
Regarding sed 's/\"[0\\.Na]\\+ EUR\"//g':

's/whatever//g' = remove all non-overlapping strings matching that regexp from each line.
\" = usually* a literal " with an unnecessary escape (\) before it.
[0\\.Na] = a bracket expression containing the characters 0, \, ., N, and a (Note: the meaning of \ inside a bracket expression depends on the char that follows it and the version of the tool you're running since some versions of some tools allow \ to escape ^, -, and ] inside bracket expressions).
\\+ = a literal \ followed by a literal +.
 EUR = a blank followed by the string EUR.
\" = usually* a literal " with an unnecessary escape (\) before it.

Regarding sed '/^\"[^\"]*\",\\+\$/d':

'/whatever/d' = remove lines that contain strings matching that regexp.
^ = the start of an input line.
\" = usually* a literal " with an unnecessary escape (\) before it.
[^\"] = a bracket expression containing any characters except \ and ".
* = 0-or-more repetitions of strings matching the preceding bracket expression.
\" = usually* a literal " with an unnecessary escape (\) before it.
, = a literal ,.
\\+  = a literal \ followed by a literal +.
\$ = a literal $.

*Usually
I say "usually" above because escaping a character that's already literal is actually undefined behavior per POSIX so any tool provider can make that mean whatever they like, that's exactly why tool providers can provide extensions like \< for word boundaries in GNU tools - since it's undefined by POSIX, the tool provider can define it to mean whatever they like so then you need to read the man page for that version of that tool to find out what it means in that context. I'm personally not aware of any tool that treats \" as anything other than just " but YMMV now or in future so just don't write \" if you want ".
